# Why my WKWebview inside my UIScrollView is not displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, loading, wkwebview

I need to add a WKWebview to load web content, inside the content view of UIScrollView.

[image]

I'm using the Apple code to load a web page, my outlet `viewForWebview` is linked correctly, and `didFinish` is called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var viewForWebview: UIView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let myConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: myConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        viewForWebview = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com.au")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finished navigating to url \(String(describing: webView.url))")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

But my the WKWebview is blank:

[image]

Just to test, I tried to display the WKWebview directly inside the content view of the scroll view, and it works.

Why is it not working as subview of the content?

Comment: Your frame is set to zero. ```webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: myConfiguration) ``` try adding constraints for WkWebView. Also add the webview to the subview instead.

```viewForWebview.addSubview(webView)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't override loadView for such actions , you need

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var viewForWebview: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let myConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame:.zero, configuration: myConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        viewForWebview.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForWebview.topAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForWebview.bottomAnchor),
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForWebview.leadingAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForWebview.trailingAnchor)

        ])

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finished navigating to url \(String(describing: webView.url))")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed on iPhone X/Xs/Xs, even if the webview top constraint is set to 0 with viewForWebview, the webview appears crop on top, do you know a solution?