# Swift: WKWebView not showing in UIScrollView

Tags: swift

I am embedding a WKWebView inside a UIScrollView but currently the webView isn't showing up.

```
class ArticleView: UIScrollView, WKNavigationDelegate {

    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let v = WKWebView()
        v.navigationDelegate = self
        v.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        v.isOpaque = false
        v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var webViewHeightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(webView)

        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}


class ArticleController: UIViewController {
    let articleView: ArticleView = {
        let v = ArticleView()
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {

        //Setup main content views
        view.addSubview(articleView)

        articleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        articleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        articleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        articleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let htmlString = //Some html string
        articleView.webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    }
```

I have implemented most suggestion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107973/why-my-wkwebview-inside-my-uiscrollview-is-not-displayed) but somehow the contents are not showing.

Comment: Why do you embed webview in scrollview?

Comment: @Frankenstein Because I would like to add other uiviews to the end of the webview.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html

Comment: @Koh, did you find a clean way?